# Word order: "played with my friend in the garden" or "played in the garden with my friend"?

Tags: word-order

Help me please with word order. For example:

> "I played tennis *in the garden* **with my friend**."
>   "I played tennis **with my friend** *in the garden*."

Are they both grammatically correct?

Answer (score 4):

They are both correct.  I would say that the first phrase gets a bit more emphasis than the second.  Some languages are more rigorous about this than English; in German for example the rule is "time manner place" or "I played tennis today with my friend in the garden."  In English, the rule (which is often broken) is "manner place time", so "I played tennis with my friend in the garden today."  In all cases you can put "today" at the beginning: "Today I played tennis in the garden with my friend."  (As you can see, I have broken the rule here, simply because "my friend in the garden" has a faint feeling of a friend who only inhabits the garden.)

For a couple of good discussions, see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79547/the-royal-order-of-adverbs) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/82776/adverbs-position-in-english-placemannertime-or-mannerplacetime).